# Need help for a regex

Tags: regex

I'd like to build a regex, but I'm stuck.

This is the format I'm looking for:

x;y => 7 times, separated by -

where x is a number from 1 to 7

and y is a number from 1 to 4

Here's what I've done so far:

```
^([0-7;&-]*)$
```

example :
1;1-2;3-3;1-4;4-5;2-6;2-7;4

Could you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Try `^[1-7];[1-4](?:-[1-7];[1-4]){6}$` https://regex101.com/r/NEweFd/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current pattern is a broad match as repeating your character class does not take any structure into account or different ranges for the digits.

You could match a digit 1-7, then `:` and a digit 1-4. Then repeat 6 times the same pattern preceded with a hyphen.

```
^[1-7];[1-4](?:-[1-7];[1-4]){6}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dUUalb/1)